# Why can't images preserve intersections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

It is a well-known fact that

$$f\Big( \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha \Big) \subset \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} f(A_\alpha)$$

but that the subsethood does not follow in the other direction. But I have designed a proof for the other direction for which I cannot find an error. I seek guidance in finding the mistake in my proof.

*Proof.*

Let $y \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} f(A_\alpha)$. By definition of intersection, we must have

$$\forall \, \alpha \in \Lambda, y \in f(A_\alpha)$$

Now by definition of image, $\exists \, x \in A_\alpha$ such that $f(x) =y$. So we can rewrite the above statement as

$$\forall \, \alpha \in \Lambda, f(x) \in f(A_\alpha)$$

But if $f(x) \in f(A_\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$, then $x \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$  and so

$$x \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha$$

But then

$$f(x) = y \in f \Big( \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha \Big)$$

And so we have shown

$$\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} f(A_\alpha) \subset f\Big( \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha \Big)$$

---

Now, I understand that we can give the classic counterexample:

$$A_1 = \{a_1\} \hspace{0.5cm} A_2 = \{a_2\} \hspace{0.5cm} f(x) = a_1$$

So $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) = \{a_1\}$ and $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$. Then the contradiction is that $\{a_1\} \subset \varnothing$.

I'm not looking for counterexamples. I'm looking for where my proof went wrong. I think my error is in assuming that $f(x) \in f(A_\alpha) \implies x \in A_\alpha$ since we could have that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: You may want to include the tag [solution-verification] for your question.

Comment: @soupless Done.

Comment: You've written $\exists x \in A_\alpha$ without ever choosing the $x$.  To choose it, we'd have $x_\alpha \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, so possibly a different $x_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.  (this is equivalent to the error you comment about in the end regarding the possibility $f$ is not injective, so in a sense, you make the same error twice)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the property desired (the one with equality for any family of subsets of the domain) is true if and only if the function $f$ is injective. Also the property is true (with equality) for any function $f$ if instead of arbitrary subsets $A_\alpha$ of the domain one has that $A_\alpha$ are all "saturated" i.e. $f^{-1}(f(A_\alpha))=A_\alpha$.